# Is there a way to run an arbitrary Visualforce page in Lightning Experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, lightning-ready

We have several very occasional use Visualforce pages that we run in Classic by entering the URL:

```
/apex/pagename
```

I presume there is no way to do this in Lightning Experience? So telling users to switch to Classic to run the pages is the way to go?

(Would be useful to be able to do this when checking if a Visualforce page works in Lightning Experience to.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more Googling shows that this subject is discussed in the [Developing Visualforce Pages for Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_process) Trailhead module. The solution for ad-hoc pages is, with Lightning Experience displayed, to execute this:

```
$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({"url": "/apex/pagename"}).fire();
```

in the JavaScript console.

Comment: VM5868:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $A is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1